# Rails: RESTful resources: Worth using or inflexible/overrated?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, rails-routing

I've been messing about in rails the past 2 months and so far everything's going well - but there's one area I'm a little doubtful on.

I keep hearing about the joys of RESTful rails resources: that is, a 'resource :foo' in config/routes, and your 7 restful actions in the controller.

Except for very simple things (eg stuff that's 99% done by running 'generate scaffold'), I find it's less convenient to try squeeze my project functionality into that approach than to just match urls in config/routes one-by-one and do each action as needed.

But I keep getting the sense that I'm wrong, and that in all but the most extreme circumstances, RESTful resources are the way to go.

So:

(a) Can anyone offer an opinion on this?

(b) For experienced rails folks, what % of your routes in a typical project are :resources and what % are coded action-by-action?
Cheers...

Comment: This is a subjective question, and I'm sure it will lead to a huge debate :)

Comment: Agreed. The fact that the question includes "Can anyone offer an opinion on this?" is asking for trouble.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Resources are convenient, but they are not a "one size fits all" feature. Some things just don't make sense with the 7 methods.

Keep in mind that [you can](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Resources/resources):

- Exclude specific methods with `:except`.
- Include only specific methods with `:only`.
- Add your own methods to the resource.

So they aren't as inflexible as you may think. But if, after taking those 3 points in mind, the resource just doesn't "feel right", **skip it**! REST was never meant to replace regular routing, it just tries to abstract away the most common use case.

If you skip out on RESTful resources completely, you'll be missing a ton of free functionality. Use it wisely and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Generally I start a project with the REST architecture in mind.  I build out my basic functionality this way, but as the project/website progresses I write more and more views that do not fit into the RESTful architecture.  Marketing sites and parallel functionality are perfect examples of this.

Here is an article on the approach:

http://ablogaboutcode.com/2010/11/22/to-be-or-not-to-be-restful-ruby-on-rails-best-practices/

---

Before you get started, here are some questions you might want to ask yourself:

1. Does this controller/view deal primarily with an object/entity like a Post, Blog?
2. Are create, update, delete, edit and new actions all going to be available on the web?

As a guideline, if you answer YES to these two questions, then it’s probably best to start with REST and expect that you will eventually use the architecture as a building block for additional actions and views you might want to perform. Otherwise, pick a URL that best represents what the action will show or do (/archives, /tour, /december-offer) and make sure you use the proper HTTP Protocols (GET for display, PUT for update, DELETE for removing and POST for creating).